# Define User Input Within a Range

Tags: c, io, floating-point

I have code where I receive floating point values from the user and manipulate them. Now I would just like to restrict the user input values within the range of [-100,000 to +100,000].

Would I do this by defining INT_MIN and INT_MAX using the limits library? Everything I see online explains that the maximum value here is +32767, minimum -32768, where the numbers are larger if I were to use LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX.

Is there a way to customize the range? Would it be a mistake to use integer methods for floats?

Comment: How are you getting the input values?

Comment: I am receiving via scanf().

Comment: Check the values after tha `scanf()`.

Comment: _Would it be a mistake to use integer methods with floats?_ Usually.  But most of the time the solution is easy enough, just use float methods for floats, i.e., instead of `abs()` for example, use `fabs()`.  But you _can_ do comparisons ***Some*** comparisons between floats and ints with no problem.  e.g.:  `if(fabs(x) > 100000){//do this}` is perfectly functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a way to customize the range?*

It is not advisable for you to change the macros ***[INT_MIN or INT_MAX](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm)*** because `limits.h` (where these macros are defined) is likely to be used elsewhere.

Nevertheless,the answer to your question is ***Yes***:
Use printf() and scanf().  Do something like:

```
#define ABS_LIMIT 100000  //create your own custom limits 
int absoluteLimit = 200000;//initialize out of acceptable range
                           //to force user input
while(fabs(absoluteLimit) >=  ABS_LIMIT)//will force accepted value to be in 
{                                       //in range of +/-100000
    printf("enter value:\n");
    scanf("%d", &absoluteLimit);
}
```

This limits the input to +/- 100000 without editing `INT_MIN` or `INT_MIN`

Comment: Suggest `if (input >= lower && input <= upper)`

Comment: @chux - made the edit, but OP never specified whether domain of valid values includes endpoints.  The phrase _within the range of_ can be interpreted either way  :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to specify the values for `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX`.

It isn't clear how you are accepting input values, but if you are reading them from a console, you could check each value after being read and, if it isn't acceptable, ask for it again, repeating until an acceptable value is entered (the word "repeating" is a hint that you'll need a loop).

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are constants, it won't be really simple to change them. Plus, they are for integers, not for floating point numbers

Correct way to check the input is to check the input:

```
if (fabs(input) > 100.0){
    //exception handling - write a message about wrong input
}
//process the numbers
```

Comment: Other than asserting that this method is the _Correct way_, your answer is on the right track.  There are other methods (constructs) that would work better.  For example ***[fabs()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/)*** instead of `abs()`, since input is in floating point:  `if(fabs(input) > 100000){...};` (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Check this idea

```
#include <stdio.h>

float getNumber(float minimum, float maximum)
{
    int   result;
    int   chr;
    float value;

    result = 0;
    do {
        printf("Input a value between %g and %g > ", minimum, maximum);

        result = scanf("%f", &value);
        /* remove all characters from the stream until the `'\n'` is found */
        while (((chr = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));
    } while ((result != 1) || (value <= minimum) || (value >= maximum));

    return value;
}

int
main()
{
    float value;

    value = getNumber(1.0, 10.0);
    printf("%f\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

this program will loop until a valid value is input by the user.

Comment: `while ((chr = fgetc(stdin)) && (chr != '\n'));` will remove until a `'\0'` or `'\n'` is encountered.  Usually a search for `EOF` and `'\n'` is done.